# solutions for rapid front-end development?

Tags: language-agnostic

im using mvc framework and i have learned some techniques that help me with different parts of RAD.

- models: doctrine/visual paradigm
- controllers/libraries: various design patterns

now i only need to know what technique/solution i should use for the views so that i can create views more rapidly.

cause i don't think it's efficient to code css/html manually, even though i understand it. its the same principle when using visual paradigm to create both my mysql database tables and doctrine model classes. i believe in using right tools will boost up development speed.

so what could i use for the views to save time and energy so i don't reinvent the wheel all the time and can focus on the business logic rather than html/css for everything? of course i would have to step in and fine tune with it when needed.

- dreamweaver?
- any css generation tools?
- 960/blueprint for layout?
- suggestions?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I've made a previous answer about developing websites without using HTML or CSS, there might be something relevant.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728690/alternatives-to-html-for-website-creation/2728748#2728748) The solutions in that answer are mostly related to "desktop class webapps", i.e. applications not websites.

Apart from that I will say that blueprint and 960gs are both very good solutions for doing normal website applications (webapps?). Things like grids etc. are extremely helpful and will speed up the development. You still have to use HTML and CSS.

I wouldn't recommend Dreamweaver,  I have never used it, but I believe that you would still have to edit in the bits and pieces to insert the content, so it probably won't be a good solution in the long run.

Comment: cs5 looks nice...i never used it though...but when it comes to frontend one could/should adopt WYSIWYG. it makes it faster to create views, but ive heard the code generated is a mess. so we'll see=)